# Extract single points of interest from OSM when described both as nodes and ways

Tags: openstreetmap, point-of-interest

I extracted both nodes and ways from [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) in PostgreSQL with [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis). I'm looking for all restaurants in a given area. The issue is that some of them are coded in OSM as nodes and others as ways.

How is it possible to have only one point when it is represented both as a node and a way?

The intuitive answer is to intersect the ways with the nodes. If a node is inside a way, they will both count as one. Otherwise, if there is only a node or only a way without nodes inside, it's fine.

The 'geometry' column in the 'ways' table does not contain information (it has something like a geometry, but all values are similar). Or maybe it is possible to use the 'nodes' table?

The fundamental question is: How is it possible to have a proper geometry column in PostgreSQL with Osmosis?

Comment: PLease stop crossposting as this consumes a lot of time of our community. You have already answers over there: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/32366/extract-single-points-of-interest-from-osm-when-described-both-as-nodes-and-ways

Comment: Is it better to post here or on help.openstreetmap in your opinion?

Comment: Your question is focused on OSM, so I would recommend to post over there, as there are more mapper. Maybe it's also worth to ask at a mailinglist. But before you do so, I would suggest to give the answers a try and than ask for resulting problems and where you fail.

Comment: Note that having multiple elemnts for the same feature is clearly a tagging [error](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/One_feature,_one_OSM_element) and should be corrected.

Comment: @scai does it mean cleaning is not necessary and there should not be mistakes (or at least not so many)? I'm a bit surprised by your comments because it is also possible to read that amenities should be both, ways and nodes: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/3824/should-amenities-eg-supermarkets-be-ways-or-nodes

Comment: @Antonin No, you are misreading. Amenities (and many other features) can be both, nodes *or* ways. But they *should not* be both at the same time. Nodes are less precise, but easier to add. Ways usually require some more surveying or good aerial imagery but they describe the feature more accurately. So nodes get *replaced* by ways from time to time. Of course inexperienced mappers or bad imports may create both, but that should occur only rarely. Depends on the area, though.